# TimerConsumer [WARN] Error processing exchange. Exchange[Message: [Body is null]]

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I have been using camel 2.10.0 for quite some time but I need to upgrade to 2.11.1 to add some functionality.  But before I got started I started getting this error after I upgraded.  I tried searching for a solution but am having difficulty finding one.  This is my route:

```
<route>
    <from uri="timer://lrbTimer?period=10s" />  
    <setBody>
        <constant>Select * from Table </constant>
    </setBody>
    <to uri="jdbc:DbConnection" />
    <filter>
        <simple>${in.body} != "[]"</simple>
        <process ref="markRecord" />
        <to uri="seda:process" />
    </filter>
</route>
```

The message I am receiving is:

> TimerConsumer [WARN] Error processing exchange. Exchange[Message: [Body is null]]. Caused by: [java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException - Index: 0, Size: 0] java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: You have some code that causes that IndexOutOfBoundsException which Camel now logs. So find the problem from the stacktrace and try to fix it

Comment: Thanks @ClausIbsen, I think I found the issue described in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the issue.  First here is the stack trace.

```
2015-01-30 15:13:47 TimerConsumer [WARN] Error processing exchange.  Exchange[Message: [Body is null]]. Caused by: [java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException - Index: 0, Size: 0]
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jdbc.JdbcProducer.setResultSet(JdbcProducer.java:226)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jdbc.JdbcProducer.createAndExecuteSqlStatement(JdbcProducer.java:146)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jdbc.JdbcProducer.processingSqlBySettingAutoCommit(JdbcProducer.java:82)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jdbc.JdbcProducer.process(JdbcProducer.java:63)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:122)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:298)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:117)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.BacklogTracerInterceptor.process(BacklogTracerInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:391)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:273)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:46)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:335)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:117)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:46)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.processAsync(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:150)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:117)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.processNext(RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.java:48)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:99)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:86)
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:135)
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:63)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
```

So I dug into the org.apache.camel.component.jdbc.JdbcProducer.setResultSet

As of camel 2.10.0 this class looked like:

```
protected void setResultSet(Exchange exchange, ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    List<Map<String, Object>> data = extractResultSetData(rs);

    exchange.getOut().setHeader(JdbcConstants.JDBC_ROW_COUNT, data.size());
    exchange.getOut().setBody(data);
}
```

In camel 2.11.1 it looks like this:

```
protected void setResultSet(Exchange exchange, ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    List<Map<String, Object>> data = extractResultSetData(rs);

    exchange.getOut().setHeader(JdbcConstants.JDBC_ROW_COUNT, data.size());
    exchange.getOut().setHeader(JdbcConstants.JDBC_COLUMN_NAMES, data.get(0).keySet());
    exchange.getOut().setBody(data);
}
```

In the cases that the error is received is when there is an empty result set.  So when version(2.11.1) looks for the column_names it fails. The good thing is that I can still use camel-jdbc(2.10.0), and still use camel-core(2.11.1) without any dependency issues.  So my fix for now is to use camel-jdbc(2.10.0)

Comment: Just to note this was fixed as of camel 2.11.2